# Updating column where other column matches criteria not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to store an object in the 'INFOOBJ' field for further processing later, but only if

```
'ADRESSE STATUS AVKLARING' == 'Ikke aktuelt'
```

If I just store text in the field, things works as expected:

```
df.loc[(df['ADRESSE STATUS AVKLARING'] == 'Ikke aktuelt'), 'INFOOBJ'] = 'This is a test'
```

Here, only lines with 'Ikke aktuelt' in the 'ADRESSE STATUS AVKLARING' field is updated.

This is my current code

```
df.loc[(df['ADRESSE STATUS AVKLARING'] == 'Ikke aktuelt'), 'INFOOBJ'] = df['FULLADR'].map(lambda x: kv.lookup(x))
```

When I run this, the lambda function is run on every line in my dataframe, and not just the ones where `'ADRESSE STATUS AVKLARING' == 'Ikke aktuelt'`. Why is this? How can I work around it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your Boolean mask on both sides of your assignment. Note `lambda` is unnecessary.

```
mask = df['ADRESSE STATUS AVKLARING'] == 'Ikke aktuelt'
df.loc[mask, 'INFOOBJ'] = df.loc[mask, 'FULLADR'].map(kv.lookup)
```